# I changed a server and a domain in the same time and the site brings error 500 in the browser

Tags: 500-internal-error

I moved a site from one server to another and it doesn't go up (500 http error) even though:

1. DB is uploaded with the same DB-name, DB user-name, and DB password.
2. wp-config.php has the same respective details.
3. Posix permissions are fine recursively (D:755, f:644, www-data:www-data).
4. I made sure every corner in the DB has the new domain via `sudo wp search-replace 'http://a.com' 'http://b.com' --all-tables-with-prefix`
5. I deactivated all plugins via `sudo wp plugin deactivate --all`
6. `.htaccess` is in place.
7. I double checked the `a` DNS record and it is fine.

What else may be there that cause this 500 error? I guess the list is very narrow now?

Answer (score 0):

The problem happened due to a corrupted `.htaccess`,

**After all the stages above**, I removed Wordfence with wp plugin uninstall and then, after that, I recreated the .htaccess based on the formal example here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

I saved and relaunched the site and now it's working.

When the site is up reactivate all plugins and bring back Wordfence.